# Off-topic close reasons (Flagging off topic questions)

Tags: feature-request, flagging, off-topic

I just stumbled on this question [How to do UDP Transmission on ENC28J60?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/484792/how-to-do-udp-transmission-on-enc28j60)

which asks advice about a software library. I wanted to flag the question as off topic, and noticed a nice reason "this question belongs to another stack exchange site". I happily clicked it, but there were only two choices and none was correct, so I renounced (but I've made a comment) because I didn't want to say "this is **blatantly** out of topic". Or instead it is?

One of the options was "super user", nice, but I think "stack overflow" should be added. Am I right in thinking so? Can we have this handy shortcut?

Comment: @pipe I did a research here for "off topic" and "close", because that's how the procedure is called, and I didn't relate "close" to "migrate". Anyway yes, that is the thread talking about my suggestion. I upvoted the question because it proposes stackoverflow, but no answers seem to agree. Should I post an answer there?

Comment: SO used to be a migration option years ago but I think it was removed because of too many rejected migrations. That question would be a good example because library recommendations are off-topic there or if you ignore that part "Can anyone help me to do reception part" would be too broad.

Comment: @PeterJ TY for clarification.